# Is there a way to ADD/COPY both directory and file in a single ADD/COPY command (dockerfile)?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image, docker-build

In my dockerfile I am trying to ADD/COPY a file and a directory into destinationFolder. Expected output is:

```
destinationFolder/test.txt
destinationFolder/test_dir/*
```

However, in the [ADD command (as mentioned in note)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add), the directory itself is not copied, just its contents.

```
ADD test.txt test_dir /destinationFolder/
```

Is there a way to achieve the desired output using a single ADD/COPY command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 solutions depending on the exact contents of your current project directory. The base line is the same though: have all your contents in the same dir and push the content of that directory directly to a target dir inside your image.

Moreover, as described in [Docker best practice](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy), I suggest you use `COPY` instead of `ADD` if you don't need any special functionalities from the latest.

## Move your contents to a separate folder

All contents you want to push to your destination folder can be placed in a dedicated folder you push at once:

In your project dir you can

```sh
mkdir imageContents
mv test.text test_dir imageContents
```

And you modify your Dockerfile with:

```
COPY imageContents destinationFolder/
```

## Replicate the exact structure from your project root

The idea is the same except you push the root or your project directly to your image. This will also work for any other folder you put there and that is not ignored. Note that you can use this for existing folder structures to simply add some files (like in the `/etc/` structure).

Create a `.dockerignore` file to make sure you only copy the relevant contents:

```
.dockerignore
Dockerfile
.git
# Add any other files that should be out of context
# Dummy examples below
.yamllint
mysecretfiles
```

Recreate the exact file structure you want to push to your image, in your case:

```
mkdir destinationFolder
mv test.txt test_dir destinationFolder
```

Eventually add some other files you want to push to your image

```
mkdir -p etc/myapp
echo "config1=myvalue" > etc/myapp/myapp.conf
```

And modify your Docker file as:

```
COPY . /
```

## Make your own method

You can easily mix the two methods above to fit your exact needs to whatever destination in your image file.

Comment: How about creating .dockerfile with * to ignore all files. Then !filename.txt / !folder_name so that only those file/folders are available in build context. Subsequently we can do ADD . .

Comment: It's your .dockeringnore, please help yourself :) `ADD` can be done anyway in either context. Docker documentation is just stating that you should prefer `COPY` if you don't absolutely need the special powers of `ADD`.

Comment: By special powers of ADD, do you specifically mean `URLs`?

Comment: I mean exactly what is written in the link I referenced in my answer: `That’s because it’s more transparent than ADD. COPY only supports the basic copying of local files into the container, while ADD has some features (like local-only tar extraction and remote URL support) that are not immediately obvious. Consequently, the best use for ADD is local tar file auto-extraction into the image, as in ADD rootfs.tar.xz /`